# Making full use of 256 random bits when you just need 1 bit

Tags: c, performance, random

I am doing some Monte Carle simulations. A CSPRNG is too expensive, so I'm using the [xoshiro256**](http://xoshiro.di.unimi.it) generator instead, which as its name suggests fills four 64-bit unsigned integers with random bits.

In my use case, only one random bit is required each time, but only extracting the lowest bit seems a huge waste.

```
static uint64_t s[4] = { /* SEED */ };

static inline unsigned random_bernoulli(void) {
    next(s);
    return s[0] & 1U;
}
```

How can I make full use of the 256 bits, preferably in a not-so-CPU-intensive way? Or, is the lowest bit random enough so my current approach is good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy. Keep your bits.

```
static uint64_t s[4] = { /* SEED */ };

static inline unsigned random_bernoulli(void) {
    static uint64_t accum[4];
    static int counter = -1;
    static int bit = 0;
    if (counter < 0) {
        next(s);
        accum[0] = s[0];
        accum[1] = s[1];
        accum[2] = s[2];
        accum[3] = s[3];
        counter = 3;
        bit = 63;
    }
    unsigned value = (accum[counter] >> bit) & 1U;
    if (--bit < 0) {
        bit = 63;
        --counter;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: I wonder what's the purpose of copying the buffer to `accum`. I suppose simply using `s` is fine? Interestingly, copying everything over *does* give a slight performance gain (< 10%)

Comment: @nalzok: Depends on whether or not anybody is allowed to all `next()` with the same buffer or not. I literally can't tell with a snippet.

Comment: I thought that would be even better because other callers could act as extra stirring? Sorry for the confusion anyway; this function is only called in one place.